# How to generate doc for OCaml based on module signatures?

Tags: ocaml, ocamldoc

I have `a.ml` like this:

```
module type ASig = 
  sig 
    val do_something : unit -> int;;
  end ;;

module A:ASig = 
  struct 
    let do_something () = 1;;
    let do_secrectly () = 2;;
  end;;
```

**So for my module A, the interface should be only `do_something()`.**

---

But if I use `ocamldoc -html a.ml`, although the module sig declares the interfact, the doc still exposes all functions in module A like:

```
module A: sig .. end
val do_something : unit -> int
val do_secrectly : unit -> int
```

---

**How should I use `ocamldoc` so that all documents are based on `module sig`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, not possible with the current implementation of ocamldoc: it takes constraint into account but at a purely syntactical level, it can only use them when they are of the explicit form `sig ... end` instead of referring to an existing identifier (because the analysis is done by hand on the parsed syntax tree, and not on the typed tree).

You can either:

- use a `.mli` and document there (if you only provide the .mli, only what's in it will be documented)
- or use the markup `(**/**)` to tell ocamldoc to discard the rest of the module, module type, etc., before the functions you want to keep private.

Comment: `or use the markup (**/**) to tell ocamldoc to discard the rest of the module, module type, etc., before the functions you want to keep private.` is very helpful enough, thank you. If you could pls bold that part in your email, that would be nice as that part is actually answering this question.

Comment: It looks like there is some work in progress to address some of these issues with codoc: https://opam.ocaml.org/blog/codoc-0-2-0-released/ a newer ocamldoc generator.